# PlayFramework 2.0 - Not able to call functions from other templates

Tags: templates, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to place some helper functions in another file, since they will be overly reused. I took the Computer-Databse sample's listing file:

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/computer-database/app/views/list.scala.html

I created a new file, called "listing.scala.html" under the app/views package, and moved the @link function from the original file to it. This new file looks like this:

```
@(currentSortBy: String, currentOrder: String, currentFilter: String)

@****************************************
* Helper generating navigation links    *
****************************************@
@link(newPage:Int, newSortBy:String) = @{

    var sortBy = currentSortBy
    var order = currentOrder

    if(newSortBy != null) {
        sortBy = newSortBy
        if(currentSortBy == newSortBy) {
            if(currentOrder == "asc") {
                order = "desc"
            } else {
                order = "asc"
            }
        } else {
            order = "asc"
        }
    }

    // Generate the link
    routes.Application.listPerfil(newPage, sortBy, order, currentFilter)

}
```

So, on my original file, I replaced the @link call, with this one:

```
<a href="@listing(currentSortBy, currentOrder, currentFilter).link(0, key)">@title</a>
```

And the problem is, when I try to compile I get this error:

```
value link is not a member of play.api.templates.Html
```

But according to the documentation (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTemplateUseCases) it seems to be ok.

Any guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play's templates aren't the best place for placing advanced conditions, most probably you'll get better flexibility by processing it in some controller (or other method) which will return you only required link

ie.:

```
 <a href="@controllers.Application.link(currentSortBy, currentOrder, currentFilter, 0, key)">@title</a>
```

In your case proposed `link(...)` function of `Application` controller can also return a reverse-route.

Keep in mind that including other templates is best option for repeating blocks of HTML but sometimes it's hard to get specified string (mainly because of not trimmed spaces). As you can see there is also problem with calling nested functions. Most probably you can generate whole `A` tag in the `listing.scala.html` however using it isn't comfortable enough (IMHO).

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. It didn't occur to me to make use of the controller since this is a view-related function, thus it should not be on the controller. And the documentation encourages this usage, afterall. Unfortunatelly it does not work. I think I'll give it a last shot by creating a single HTML file called link. If it works I'll risk elegancy by having a few single-functions files, in order to avoid code duplication.

Comment: For sure formating blocks is task for templates however creating the correct routes can be considered as part of logic. Take a look: you are using `routes.Application.listPerfil(newPage, sortBy, order, currentFilter)` in your view which is a non-view function, so I don't see anything wrong with 'wrapping' it in your own function/method. Of course it's your choice, you can do it in seconds with controller or still 'fight' with templating system :)

Comment: Allright, I gave up on it. I managed to make it work with a single-function view file, but then I realized that I would have to parametrize the link generation, and that would compromise the code readability. Thus, I'll leave the code duplication, and keep eagle eyes over the code. :)